# How to load encrypted bitcoin wallet.dat file in javascript?

Tags: bitcoin, wallet

I am trying to load the wallet.dat file in my react native app.
So far the function that I found online is not working.
Is there any effective way to load a bitcoin encrypted wallet.dat file in my application?
Wallet.dat has been created with the bitcoin core app.

function to parse wallet.dat file

```js
var parseWalletdat = function parseWalletdat(data) {
    var re = /\x30\x81\xD3\x02\x01\x01\x04\x20(.{32})/gm;
    var dataHexStr = data.toString('latin1');
    privateKeys = dataHexStr.match(re);

    if (!privateKeys) {
      return 'wallet is encrypted?';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an encrypted Bitcoin wallet you wouldn't see the B?Der keys with just that search, even on an unencrypted wallet you wouldn't.

I suggest searching for a public key. and encoding the values into a bitcoin address for checking the balance.

Comment: I am trying to build a cross-platform app that can import wallets from other platforms like Bitcoin core, etc. If the wallets are encrypted, I have to prompt the user for the key.


So far, https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet.git, this repo has helped to extract the public keys and give private keys in encrypted form. But this needs to be done on the server, which is not secure that much.


Trying to find a different approach to decrypt the encrypted wallets from other platforms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: check out my research on github https://github.com/hashcashinfo/wallet-recovery/tree/main/research